# error con mi apk de react native con expo

Tags: react-native

hice mi aplicación de react native utilizando expo, una to do list app, la terminé y proseguí a hacer el apk con "expo build:android" hasta acá todo correcto, ningún error y pude generar mi apk. el problema es que cuando quiero iniciar mi app en mi dispositivo me dice que la app se detuvo y se cierra al instante, solamente puedo visualizar el splash. No encuentro el error y no sé que podría ser, busqué mas formas de hacer el apk pero me termina dando el mismo error, en el emulador aparece perfectamente mi app, el  problema es cuando la utilizo  en mi dispositivo.

```html
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Keyboard, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Task from './components/Task';

export default function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState();
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);

  const handAddTask = () =>   {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
    setTask(null);
  }

  const completeTask = (index) =>  {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
  }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Added this scroll view to enable scrolling when list gets longer than the page */}
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1
        }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
      >

       <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
         <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Tareas para hoy</Text>

         <View style={styles.items}>
          {
            taskItems.map((item, index) => {
             return (
               <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
             <Task text={item}/>
               </TouchableOpacity>
             )
            })
          }
         {/* <Task text={'Task 1'} />
         <Task text={'Task 2'}/> */}
         </View>
       </View>
       </ScrollView>


       <KeyboardAvoidingView
       behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
       style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
       >
         <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder= {'Que necesitas hacer?'} value={task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)}/>

         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handAddTask()}>
           <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
             <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
           </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </KeyboardAvoidingView>

      </View>
    )
  }



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:  {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#E8EAED"
  },
  tasksWrapper:   {
    paddingTop: 40,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
sectionTitle:   {
  fontSize: 28,
  fontWeight: "bold",

},
items:  {
  marginTop: 30,
},
writeTaskWrapper: {
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 20,
  width: '100%',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-around',
  alignItems: 'center',
  position: 'fixed'
},
input:  {
  paddingVertical: 15,
  paddingHorizontal: 15,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 60,
  borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
  borderWidth: 1,
  width: 250,
},
addWrapper: {
  width: 60,
  height: 60,
  backgroundColor: '#55BCF6',
  borderRadius: 60,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
  borderWidth: 1,
},
addText:  {
  fontSize: 40,
  color: '#fff',
  textAlign: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  position: 'center',
  fontWeight: "bold",
  marginBottom: 10,
},
})
```

Comment: Encontraste la solución? A mi tambien me hace lo.mismo.

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo, realmente no se porque. Es crear una app von expo e intentar crear una apk y la app nunca abre. Cierra por error, solo muestra el splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

Después de 3 horas de búsqueda y análisis en mi aplicación no vi nada malo, hasta que quité una línea de comando: si estás utilizando Hermes con expo debes eliminar la línea de código que colocaste en tu *app.json*

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "jsEngine": "hermes" // Esta linea la debes quitar
   }
}
```

Luego crea el APK con `expo build:android` o del sistema operativo que vayas a utilizar, una vez descargado lo instalas y comprueba si funciona.

Esto dice la documentación de expo: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-hermes/

> **Limitaciones**
> Las aplicaciones independientes creadas con expo build no son compatibles.
> El sistema de compilación clásico no es lo suficientemente flexible como para admitir el uso de Hermes para algunas aplicaciones y no para otras. Deberá usar el nuevo sistema de compilación, EAS Build, para usar Hermes en sus aplicaciones independientes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes buscar mas sobre el error si conectas tu dispositivo por usb en modo de depuración y revisas el log.

Tu código se ve bien, sin embargo, en React **no debes dejar código comentado dentro del return**, en producción llega a causar errores en ciertas situaciones, puede que sea tu caso.